# tkInter nested canvas's not display full contents of frames

Tags: tkinter, canvas, nested, scrollbar

I'm trying to build an appointment type application.  I need nested Scrollbars to simulate an Excel 'freeze top row' type of function.  I may have too many columns to fit conveniently, so I've put a horizontal scrollbar on a frame in a canvas.  Then, I may have too many rows, so I've got a vertical scrollbar nested into another canvas/frame combo.  The horizontal scroll needs to scroll the 'titles' and the detail contents.  The vertical scroll just need to scroll the detail contents within the columns.  I've got this working, but I cannot get a 'full display'.  Somewhere one of the outer frames seems to be limiting everything else.
This is the outline of the code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

i1 = 10  #testing number of columns
j1 = 20  #testing number of rows

root = tk.Tk()
full_frame = ttk.Frame(root, border=8, relief="ridge")
full_frame.grid(row=0,column=0)

buttons_frame = ttk.Frame(full_frame, border=8, relief="ridge")
buttons_frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky="w")
#user control buttons will go here
l = ttk.Label(buttons_frame, text = "buttons frame ")
l.grid (row=0, column = 0)

#build horizontally scrollable frame
dispatch_frame = ttk.Frame(full_frame,border=8, relief="ridge")
dispatch_frame.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="w")

h_canvas = tk.Canvas(dispatch_frame)
h_canvas.grid(row=0,column=0)

h_scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(dispatch_frame, orient="horizontal", command=h_canvas.xview)
h_scrollbar.grid(row=2, column = 0, columnspan = 1, sticky="s,e,w")

horiz_frame = ttk.Frame(h_canvas,border=8, relief="ridge")
horiz_frame.grid(row=0,column=0)

horiz_frame.bind("<Configure>", lambda e: h_canvas.configure(scrollregion=h_canvas.bbox("all")))

h_canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=horiz_frame, anchor="nw")
h_canvas.configure(xscrollcommand=h_scrollbar.set)

#add techs (column titles)
tech_frame=ttk.Frame(horiz_frame, border=8, relief="ridge")
tech_frame.grid(row=0,column=0)

for i in range(i1):
    l = ttk.Label(tech_frame, text = "tech "+str(i), width=10)
    l.grid (row=1, column = i)

#build job frame
job_frame=ttk.Frame(horiz_frame, border=8, relief="ridge", width=horiz_frame.winfo_reqheight())
job_frame.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="e,w")

v_canvas = tk.Canvas(job_frame)
v_canvas.grid(row=0,column=0)

v_scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(job_frame, orient="vertical", command=v_canvas.yview)
v_scrollbar.grid(row = 0, column = 1, rowspan = 1 , sticky="e,n,s")

v_frame=ttk.Frame(v_canvas,border=8, relief="ridge", width = 10 * i1)
v_frame.grid(row=0,column=0, sticky="e,w")

v_frame.bind("<Configure>", lambda e: v_canvas.configure(scrollregion=v_canvas.bbox("all")))

v_canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=v_frame, anchor="nw")
v_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=v_scrollbar.set)

#populate rows for each column
for i in range(i1):
    for j in range(j1):
        l1 = ttk.Label(v_frame, text = " Row: " + str(j), width=10)
        l1.grid(row=j, column = i)

root.mainloop()
```

I've been learning python on my own for a couple months and this one has me stuck.
Thanks for any suggestions.

I was hoping for big enough outer frames/windows to hold all the controls and at least some of the data.
The horizontal seems to work OK, but I cannot see the last few columns of each row and the last few rows.  (They are hidden underneath the windows/frames).